# How execute a powershell file in a job from Jenkins?

Tags: powershell, jenkins

- Furthermore, I have the plugin for de powershell instaled.

In the configuration job, I have this:

[image: Command windows power shell]

But, I have the next error when execute the job:

```
.ps1 cannot be loaded because the
 execution of scripts is disabled on this system. Please see "get-help about_si
gning" for more details.
At line:1 char:2
+ & <<<<  'C:\Windows\TEMP\abc.ps1'
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException

Build step 'Windows PowerShell' marked build as failure
Started calculate disk usage of build
Finished Calculation of disk usage of build in 0 seconds
Started calculate disk usage of workspace
Finished Calculation of disk usage of workspace in 0 seconds
Finished: FAILURE
```

I think that this is because my instance of Jenkins not is administrator.

Note:

```
- I have a instance of Jenkins in my machine local
- And when I compile from my  windows power shell console, this if execute (This is possible with this instruction "Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the execution policy on the server.
You can set the execution policy by typing this into your powershell window:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

For more details https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176961.aspx

Comment: @HenryMartinezQ. try to add this line as a build step using powershell pluging, instead of running it directly on the machine

Answer (score -2):

Don't run Jenkins server using service... Run jenkin server in cmd window(without window service)

Comment: please answer more broader, it wouldn't hurt

Comment: If you believe that is the correct answer, please explain it.  However I strongly disagree.  When it is the CI product chosen by a company, Jenkins, whether on windows or linux, is typically the backbone of CI and controlled delivery (maybe not continuous).  Most organizations I've done dev-ops at would never run something so critical (and requiring monitoring and remote administration capabilities and self-restarting capabilities etc) as a standalone EXE.  Windows services are built from the ground up for this kind of functionality.  Why would standalone exe solve this for the poster?